# AMD Radeon performing unexpectedly bad

Tags: graphics, radeon, amdgpu

I have a PC with an integrated and a discrete GPU's

```
:~$ inxi -G
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel RocketLake-S GT1 [UHD Graphics 750] driver: i915 v: kernel
  Device-2: AMD Navi 23 [Radeon RX 6600/6600 XT/6600M] driver: amdgpu
    v: kernel
  Display: wayland server: X.Org v: 1.22.1.1 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.1
    compositor: gnome-shell v: 42.9 driver: X: loaded: modesetting gpu: i915
    resolution: 1: 2560x1440~60Hz 2: 1024x768~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: AMD Radeon RX 6600 XT (navi23 LLVM 15.0.7 DRM 3.42
  5.15.0-84-generic)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 23.3~git2310040600.a2641d~oibaf~j (git-a2641dd 2023-10-04
    jammy-oibaf-ppa)
```

By default the integrated GPU (intel) is active and I had to change it to AMD Radeon to make it the primary GPU using:
`:$ DRI_PRIME=1`.

I am benchmarking both of them using `glmark2`. The thing is that, one time the benchmarking worked very well and reported a score of `23372` for the AMD Radeon GPU. But now every time I am running the benchmarking again it keeps giving me very low score of `2582` even though none of the system settings have changed.

Any idea what or where the problem lies?